# Not sure if correct answers for substitution and "free for"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

My first question is: What is the result of the following substitution?

$[y/x](Bx \wedge \exists y Rxy)$

I would say that there is no result. Or should I say the result is $Bx \wedge \exists y Rxy$?

My second question is:

The question that's being asked: Is $f(x, y)$ free for $y$ in $Bx \wedge \exists y Rxy$?

The only $y$ in this formula is bound. Can you then also say that $f(x, y)$ free for $y$?

Edit per request: "Free for" (vrij voor in Dutch) basically means that you can replace a variable in a formula with a term. But it has to adhere to certain rules, one of which is that you cannot replace a variable in a formula that is bound by a quantifier.

Comment: Certainly there is a result. The result is the same as the original expression.

Comment: @MJD I thought so! Well, thanks for clearing that one up!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your textbook's definition of "free for"? I at least am not familiar with this term.

Comment: @MJD I amended my post, I hope you understand what I meant with free for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that we have different "flavors" according to the textbooks.

See George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008), page 132 :

> The definition of $A[x := t]$ [i.e.the substitution into formula $A$ of *term* $t$ in place of variable $x$] says that we are to replace every free occurrence of $x$ in $A$ by $t$, *but* if for some $y$ that occurs in $t$ — free, of course — there is a subformula $(\forall y)B$ [or $(\exists y)B$] of $A$ where $x$ occurs free, then we abort the operation and declare $A[x := t]$ *undefined*.

Thus, according to the following "convention", we have no result with $(Bx∧∃yRxy)[x := y]$, because there is the subformula $\exists yRxy$ with the quabtifier $\exists y$ and we do not want that it "captures" the new term $y$.

We may check on other textbooks; see Dirk van Dalen, *Logic and Structure* (5th ed - 2013), page 61 :

> $(∀yϕ)[t/x]$ is $∀yϕ$ if $x = y$ (the "equal" is in the metalanguage).

This amount to say that the substitution is not performed.

In both cases, we have that the "operation" of *substitution* is not permitted; thus the original formula stay unchanged.

Regarding the second question, in van Dalen [page 62] we have that :

> **Definition 3.3.12** $t$ is *free for* $x$ in $ϕ$ if [...]
>
> *(iii)* $ϕ := ∃yψ$ (or $ϕ := ∀yψ$) and if $x ∈ FV(ϕ)$, then $y \notin FV(t)$ and $t$ is free for $x$ in $ψ$.

In your example, the *term* $t$ is $f(x,y)$ and we want to know if it is *free for* $y$ in $ϕ$, where $ϕ$ is (simplifying a little bit) $∃yRxy$.

The answer is **NO**, because $y \notin FV(ϕ)$.

*Note.* The same rule is used by Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd - 2001), page 113, where the locution used : "the term $t$ is not *substitutable for* $x$ in $\varphi$", is intended explicitly to *prevent* wrong substitutions.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my comment, which I now see was mistaken.

Comment: Wait, what? So the result is that there is no result instead of the original formula? Or are both answers okay?

Comment: @user3488442 - if the rule means that the result is undefined, the conclusion is that you cannot do it; thus the formula stay unchanged.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Of course, thanks! I want to ask; did you understand what I meant with my second question?